# Spring Boot: Capture event on context load time and on property change

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I wanted to execute a custom logic as soon as the application started and also whenever properties change in Spring Cloud config repo/server. So I have written something like this:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentChangeEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<EnvironmentChangeEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentChangeEvent event) {
        // Custom logic goes here. It should be executed on both app context load time
        // and on any property change time

    }

}
```

This above code was working few months back during application load time and when property change. But this code stopped working recently with, I guess, Spring boot / cloud version updates.

Currently I am using **Sprig boot 1.5.10** and Cloud **Edgware.SR3**

Comment: looks like EnvironmentChangedEvent previously called on start up time but now in the newer versions it is not called on start up time.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to run the custom logic to run it on both load time and property change time.

Basically changed to above code to be called upon any event and then inside the overridden methood onApplicationEvent checking only for below event

1. **ContextRefreshedEvent** - Event raised when an application context gets initialized or refreshed.
2. **EnvironmentChangeEvent** - Event published to signal a change in the environment such as properties in config repo.

   ```
   import org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentChangeEvent;
   import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
   import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
   import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;

   public class AppConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

     @Override
     public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
       if (event instanceof EnvironmentChangeEvent || event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
          // Custom logic goes here. It should be executed on both app context load time 
          // and on any property change time
       }
     }
   }
   ```

**Updated**

We can also use **@EventListener** annotation to do the similar thing, which is very simple and easy use. Refer below example:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @EventListener({EnvironmentChangeEvent.class, ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
    public void onRefresh() {
        // Your code goes here...
    }

}
```